# iterate the result of result in ansible

Tags: ansible

When I use the below in ansible,

```
 with_items:
        - "{{ result1.results }}"
```

this is the result

```
"stderr": "",
"stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "Total Cases : 139, Total Success Cases : 137, Total Failure Cases : 2, Success Percent : 98.56%, ,",
"stdout_lines": ["Total Cases : 139, Total Success Cases : 137, Total Failure Cases : 2, Success Percent : 98.56%, ,"]
```

again how to iterate the `"stdout_lines"` in ansible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate of a list, use the loop or with_items construct.

Here is a simple role I created to display the output of ps

```
---
- name: Getting ps output
  shell: ps
  register: o
- name: Debug
  debug: var=o
- name: Display stdout of ps
  shell: echo "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ o.stdout_lines }}"
...
```

I use the playbook to run the role:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - ps
...
```

Here is the command and output:

```
ansible-playbook ./testps.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [ps : Getting ps output] **************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [ps : Debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "o": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "ps",
        "delta": "0:00:00.014101",
        "end": "2018-11-26 13:28:54.858550",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2018-11-26 13:28:54.844449",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "  PID TTY          TIME CMD\n  300 pts/0    00:00:00 sh\n  301 pts/0    00:00:00 python\n  302 pts/0    00:00:00 python\n  303 pts/0    00:00:00 sh\n  318 pts/0    00:00:00 ps\n 5229 pts/0    00:00:00 bash\n 5576 pts/0    00:00:00 bash\n32689 pts/0    00:00:00 ansible-playboo\n32752 pts/0    00:00:00 ansible-playboo\n32767 pts/0    00:00:00 sh",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "  PID TTY          TIME CMD",
            "  300 pts/0    00:00:00 sh",
            "  301 pts/0    00:00:00 python",
            "  302 pts/0    00:00:00 python",
            "  303 pts/0    00:00:00 sh",
            "  318 pts/0    00:00:00 ps",
            " 5229 pts/0    00:00:00 bash",
            " 5576 pts/0    00:00:00 bash",
            "32689 pts/0    00:00:00 ansible-playboo",
            "32752 pts/0    00:00:00 ansible-playboo",
            "32767 pts/0    00:00:00 sh"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [ps : Display stdout of ps] ***********************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=  PID TTY          TIME CMD)
changed: [localhost] => (item=  300 pts/0    00:00:00 sh)
changed: [localhost] => (item=  301 pts/0    00:00:00 python)
changed: [localhost] => (item=  302 pts/0    00:00:00 python)
changed: [localhost] => (item=  303 pts/0    00:00:00 sh)
changed: [localhost] => (item=  318 pts/0    00:00:00 ps)
changed: [localhost] => (item= 5229 pts/0    00:00:00 bash)
changed: [localhost] => (item= 5576 pts/0    00:00:00 bash)
changed: [localhost] => (item=32689 pts/0    00:00:00 ansible-playboo)
changed: [localhost] => (item=32752 pts/0    00:00:00 ansible-playboo)
changed: [localhost] => (item=32767 pts/0    00:00:00 sh)

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The ansible documentation has more info on using loops.

Hope this helps.